# Polars: What is the fastest way to loop over Polars DataFrame columns to apply transformations?

Tags: python, python-polars

Is there a preferred way to loop and apply functions to Polars columns?

Here is a pandas example of what I am trying to do:

```
    df1 = pl.DataFrame(
        {
            "A": np.random.rand(10),
            "B": np.random.rand(10),
            "C": np.random.rand(10)
        }
    )
    df2 = pl.DataFrame(
        {
            "X1": np.random.rand(10),
            "X2": np.random.rand(10),
            "X3": np.random.rand(10)
        }
    )


    # pandas code
    
    # this is just a weighted sum of df2, where the weights are from df1
    df1.to_pandas().apply(
        lambda weights: df2.to_pandas().mul(weights, axis=0).sum() / weights.sum(), axis=0,
        result_type='expand'
    )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're doing the equivalent of:

```
pd.concat(
   (df1.mul(b[col], axis=0).sum() / df1.sum() for col in df2.columns),
   axis=1
)
```

Which can be written pretty much the same way in polars:

```
pl.concat((df1 * col).sum() / df1.sum() for col in df2)
```

```
shape: (3, 3)
┌──────────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│ A        | B        | C        │
│ ---      | ---      | ---      │
│ f64      | f64      | f64      │
╞══════════╪══════════╪══════════╡
│ 0.363931 | 0.44298  | 0.431432 │
│ 0.54025  | 0.42028  | 0.418826 │
│ 0.506882 | 0.576332 | 0.61857  │
└──────────┴──────────┴──────────┘
```

It may make sense to do `weights = df1.sum()` to avoid recalculating the sum each time.

You could also do it inside a `.select()`

```
df1.select(
   weighted_sum = 
      pl.concat_list(
         (pl.all() * col).sum() / pl.all().sum()
         for col in df2)
      .reshape((len(df2.columns), -1))
      .arr.to_struct()
      .struct.rename_fields(df1.columns)
).unnest("weighted_sum")
```

```
shape: (3, 3)
┌──────────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│ A        | B        | C        │
│ ---      | ---      | ---      │
│ f64      | f64      | f64      │
╞══════════╪══════════╪══════════╡
│ 0.363931 | 0.44298  | 0.431432 │
│ 0.54025  | 0.42028  | 0.418826 │
│ 0.506882 | 0.576332 | 0.61857  │
└──────────┴──────────┴──────────┘
```

Comment: Nice. That 1-liner is 10x faster than my current implementation - much appreciated @jqurious